Error on imports when trying to use SHACL with Playwright
I am trying to do some API testing in Playwright with SHACL, and the imports
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import rdf from 'rdf-ext';
import N3Parser from '@rdfjs/parser-n3';
import fs from 'fs/promises';
import path from 'path';
import { Readable } from 'stream';

are giving me this error
Error: require() of ES Module d:\node js proj 3\node_modules\rdf-ext\index.js from d:\node js proj 3\tests\api\shacl.spec.ts not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in d:\node js proj 3\tests\api\shacl.spec.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.playwright
module "d:/node js proj 3/node_modules/@types/rdfjs__parser-n3/index"

Also my tsconfig.json file looks like this
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": [ "tests/api/shacl.spec.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

What can i do about it ?

Please check the version of your modules, typescript and node. I have the following:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.45.2",
    "@rdfjs/parser-n3": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.10",
    "@types/rdf-ext": "^2.5.0",
    "rdf-ext": "^2.5.2"
  }
}

It compiles without errors with typescript@5.5.3 and runs without errors with node@20.15.0. I used the following to build:
tsc --p tsconfig.json

And the following to run it:
node ./tests/api/shacl.spec.ts

